# Other variables changing for no reason - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a function where i loop through 2 arrays and do some logic. My issue is when i change one of the object properties in the array, they also change my base object variable and all other objects in the entire of both arrays. Even though i only want to edit specific objects properties. I dont want to paste the entire code so i will show you my vital function but also leave a link to my entire code.

```
var updateMobs = function() {

    for (var b = 0; b < mobsBlue.length; b++) {
        BM = mobsBlue[b];
        BM.x = BM.x - BM.object.speed;

        doCollision(BM, redBase, BM);
        doCollision(BM, debugPlayer, BM);

        if (BM.x < 0){
            mobsBlue.splice(b, 1);
        };

        BM.Draw(ctx, false, true, "blue")


    };
    for (var r = 0; r < mobsRed.length; r++) {
        RM = mobsRed[r];
        RM.x = RM.x + RM.object.speed;

        doCollision(RM, blueBase, RM);
        doCollision(RM, debugPlayer, RM);

        if (RM.x > ctx.canvas.width){
            mobsRed.splice(r, 1);
        };

        RM.Draw(ctx, false, true, "red")    

        for (var br = 0; br < mobsBlue.length; br++) {
            BM = mobsBlue[br];

            if (doCollision(RM, BM, collisionNull) == true) { // ATTACKING
                BM.x = BM.x + BM.object.speed;
                RM.x = RM.x - RM.object.speed;

                if (BM.object.attackTime == BM.object.attackSpeed || RM.object.attackTime == RM.object.attackSpeed) {
                    if (BM.object.armourType == 'light') {
                        BM.object.health = BM.object.health - RM.object.lightDamage;
                    };
                    if (BM.object.armourType == 'heavy') {
                        BM.object.health = BM.object.health - RM.object.heavyDamage;
                    };
                    if (RM.object.armourType == 'light') {
                        RM.object.health = RM.object.health - BM.object.lightDamage;
                    };
                    if (RM.object.armourType == 'heavy') {
                        RM.object.health = RM.object.health - BM.object.heavyDamage;

                    };
                    alert("BLUE" + BM.object.health)
                    alert("RED" + RM.object.health)
                    if (BM.object.health <= 0) {
                        mobsBlue.splice(br, 1);
                    };
                    if (RM.object.health <= 0) {
                        mobsRed.splice(r, 1);
                    };
                    BM.object.attackTime = 0;
                    RM.object.attackTime = 0;

                };
                BM.object.attackTime = BM.object.attackTime + 1;
                RM.object.attackTime = RM.object.attackTime + 1;

            };                          
            BM.Draw(ctx, false, true, "blue");
            RM.Draw(ctx, false, true, "red");
        };
    };
};
```

http://pastebin.com/TPZE3Uqu

Comment: `My issue is when i change some of the objects properties in the array, they also change my base object variable and all other objects in the entire of both arrays` - Can you please be specific?

Comment: read edit, replace 'some' with 'one'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

OR
In ECMAScript 6 there is Object.assign method, which copies values of all enumerable own properties from one object to another.

For example:

```
var x = {myProp: "value"};
var y = Object.assign({}, x); //shallow copy
```

OR in jQuery

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject); // Shallow copy
```

`var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);` //deep copy

Comment: I was under the impression that `Object.assign` was more like `jQuery.extend({}, oldObject)` (i.e. not a deep merge)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with JavaScript's prototype inheritance.

Take a good read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

You should isolate your scope by using "var" as in:

```
var BM = mobsBlue[br];
```